# ORMLite autoGenerate date on creation

Tags: java, ormlite

I've implemented a date myself using long and I know I can persist the date in a few different ways:

http://ormlite.com/docs/types

Is there a way to from ORMLite to automatically generate the date of creation of the object?

Answer (score 0):

> I've implemented a date myself using long and I know I can persist the date in a few different ways:

If I am understanding the question, ORMLite does support the use of custom data type persisters.  See the docs on the subject:

http://ormlite.com/docs/custom-persister

To quote:

> ORMLite has internal definitions for storing the basic primitive and other common data types. See section Persisted Data Types. Sometimes, however, you either want to store a new data type in your database or you want to change the way ORMLite stores values to the database for common types – this often happens when you are trying to work with an existing schema. You can change how types are stored in the database by defining a class which implements the DataPersister interface.

There are some examples there.